# How to determine the quantity of range values?

Tags: sqlite

how to get the quantity of range values?
example:

FromMemberNo  100 ToMemberNo 101

so the QUANTITY will be 2.

```
Group  FromMemberNo      ToMemberNo    
    A             100       101            
    A             200       204            
    X             100       101            
    X             301       302           
    A             500       500            
    A             600       600
```

i want to get the quantity per range

```
  Quantity
    2
    5
    2
    2
    1
    1
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

`select (ToMemberNo-FromMemberNo+1) as Quantity from your_table;`